# how to free multiprocessing memory

Tags: memory, multiprocessing

I use apply_async, the returning data is 10000 matrix, but the problem is the data in res_list is not released, even if I set it as none. So how to free the memory in res_list. Or maybe I use multiprocessing in a wrong way.

```py
res_list = []
pool = Pool(10)
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        res_list.append(pool.apply_async(calculate, (i, j)))

pool.close()
pool.join()


result = []
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100): 
        result.append(res_list[i*100 +j].get())

res_list = None
gc.collect()
```

Comment: you are copying all the data to `result` from `res_list`, so getting rid of `res_list` won't actually free a significant amount of memory because all your values still have references inside `result` and won't be garbage collected.

Comment: could you give a more complete example?  note that closing a pool before you collect the async results doesn't seem like a great idea.  also, how do you know the problem is due to memory not being released?

Comment: @SamMason IIRC in this instance calling `close` and `join` explicitly rather than using `with Pool` avoids the call to `Pool.terminate` so technically this is fine, as `Pool.join()` should wait on all workers (and therefore all tasks) to join normally. The `handle_results` thread will be collecting output continuously while the main thread waits on `join`, so the only possible error would be an out of memory while waiting (not freeing anything while you wait) because the underlying pipe is being cleared..

Comment: @Aaron I removed the part about assigning data to result, which means set res_list to none immediately. still res_list can not be released, I checked that one res_list is created, its reference count is 3..
Can you explain a bit more about the "out of memory while waiting",why not freeing anything.  And I can get all the results back correctly.

Comment: @xuuxuu you can start processing results before waiting for all of them to be complete. For this you would have to move the processing before the pool is joined (or you'll still be waiting on all results before you start any processing). Also how are you counting memory usage?